# Why can't turn on (pause) radio button?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, radio-button

You can see here: [image]

How to find for `.js` (javascript)? This is from WooCommerce default coding. Coding from html via <kbd>F12</kbd> **"Your order"**. I copy the html and insert in Shipping page - it turns out badly. Could you help me? Thank you!

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate11" value="flat_rate:11" class="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_nova_poshta_shipping_method" value="nova_poshta_shipping_method" class="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate10" value="flat_rate:10" class="shipping_method">
```

Comment: `.js (java)?` No, `.js` is Javascript. Java is entirely different. Please post a full [MCVE] in the question itself.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting in the console?

Comment: I copied the coding from "Your Order", from Shipping. Do you know this? Here! This is a simple html. From "Your order" in the Shipping there radio button is ok.

Comment: I copied the coding from "Your order" page, and paste the Shipping page here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_nova_poshta_shipping_method" value="nova_poshta_shipping_method" class="shipping_method">
```

After

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_nova_poshta_shipping_method" value="nova_poshta_shipping_method" class="shipping_method" checked>
```